# FormData Data.Append is sending nothing to backend in react-native

Tags: react-native

this is my issue here , i cannot send data using this code  , when i debug my backend App , it shows that i didn't send body in my request otherwise the calling(get) method is working perfect

```
const endpoint = "/clientBranches";

const getBranches = () => client.get(endpoint);

const addBranch = (branchName) => {
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("clientId", "60199b1a795b423ef43d44fd");
  data.append("name", "branchName.text");
  return client.post(endpoint, data);
};
```

Comment: Can you please share how the ```client``` is initialised?

Comment: ```import { create } from "apisauce";

const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.1.3:3000/api",
});
export default apiClient;
```